# Can not check network info programmatically in battery save mode in android device

Tags: android, network-connection, android-connectivitymanager

I want to check connection state in my android app. I call the next method in `onResume`:

```
public boolean isThereInternetConnection() {
        boolean isConnected = false;
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =
                (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = (connectivityManager != null) ? connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() : null;
        if (networkInfo != null) {
            isConnected = networkInfo.isConnected();
        }
        return isConnected;
    }
```

In normal mode it works well. But when my device is on battery saver mode and I open my activity from background, method `isThereInternetConnection()` returns false sometimes (internet connection was well). For this I checked `networkInfo.getDetailedState()` and in battery saver mode it returns `DetailedState.BLOCKED` even I have good internet connection. So how to resolve this bug, how to check internet connection in battery saver mode and obtain real value true or false - connected to internet or not?

Comment: Have you tried  activeNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting() ?

Comment: Curious Mind, the method isConnectedOrConnecting() is deprecated now

Comment: What about adding conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable() to the condition, like this:
if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable() && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected())

Comment: Curious Mind, method isAvailable() is deprecated too :)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to check internet is actually pinging to the internet. Sometimes the internet is connected but no network access.

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    try {
        int timeoutMs = 1500;
        Socket sock = new Socket();
        SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress("8.8.8.8", 53);

        sock.connect(sockaddr, timeoutMs);
        sock.close();

        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) { return false; }
}
```

> The above code will not run on the main thread and requires internet
>   connectivity permission.

**The code below is a bit slow but will work on the main thread. Requires internet connectivity permission:**

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        Process ipProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8");
        int     exitValue = ipProcess.waitFor();
        return (exitValue == 0);
    }
    catch (IOException e)          { e.printStackTrace(); }
    catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    return false;
}
```

Ref: [How to check internet access on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-times-out)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method :

```
public void checkInternetAndContinue() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int timeoutMs = 1500;
                Socket sock = new Socket();
                SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress("8.8.8.8", 53);

                sock.connect(sockaddr, timeoutMs);
                sock.close();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        startWork(true);
                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        startWork(false);

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

and continue work if there is internet

```
private void startWork(boolean b) {
     if(b){
         // do whatever you want when the internet is available    
     } else {
         // No Internet.
     }
}
```

Hope it help!